# Circulant matrix inverse in $GF(p)$

Tags: computational-complexity, fourier-transform, circulant-matrices

For a polynomial $C(x)=c_0+\dots+c_n x^n$, consider a circulant matrix $C$ such that
$$
C= \begin{pmatrix}
c_0      & c_{n-1} & \cdots  & c_2     & c_1     \\
c_1      & c_0     & c_{n-1} &         & c_2     \\
\vdots   & c_1     & c_0     & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
c_{n-2}  &         & \ddots  & \ddots  & c_{n-1} \\
c_{n-1}  & c_{n-2} & \cdots  & c_1     & c_0     \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Its inverse is also a circulant matrix formed from the polynomial $C^{-1}(x) \pmod{x^n-1}$.

A classic way to find $C^{-1}(x)$ computationally is to perform discrete Fourier transform on $C(x)$, then invert the resulting values, and make the inverse transform. If one of the values is $0$, then the matrix is not invertible.

I'm considering circular matrices with elements from $GF(p)$, meaning that we would need to look for an inverse in the ring $\mathbb Z_p[x]/(x^n-1)$ rather than $\mathbb C[x]/(x^n-1)$. A significant caveat here is that unless $n$ divides $p-1$, it is not possible to conduct NTT over $GF(p)$. So far, some ways to consider on how to do this:

1. Use extended Euclidean algorithm to find $C^{-1}(x) \pmod{x^n-1}$. Best-known algorithm (half-GCD) for this seems to work in $O(n \log^2 n)$ for this, is pretty complicated and has a large constant-time overhead.
2. Try to work in a field extension of $GF(p)$ that contains the primitive root of $1$ of degree $n$. This essentially means working modulo $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial, which is most likely not doable in sub-quadratic time.
3. Find inverse in $\mathbb C[x]/(x^n-1)$. It will be rational and can be converted back to remainders modulo $p$, but the precision needed to do this is probably too high for it to be feasible.

Are there any other viable approaches here to do this in a simpler manner, or reduce the runtime to $O(n \log n)$?